# Which sounds more right in a website name/address: [product]available or available[product]?

Tags: phrases

I want to get a website name and an address, and they have to communicate that a product that's represented on the site is instantly available.

For example if I sell bread, which is better: AvailableBread.com or BreadAvailable.com ?

Thanks ;)

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: From an SEO perspective, because bread is the subject, placing bread first gets the higher ranking.

Comment: It is a name. It does not matter. You can call your company Microsoft, and you can call it Softmicro. Or Rosoftmic, or Pplea. Which is precisely why naming questions are off-topic here. You can use absolutely any combination of letters and numbers from any alphabet of your choosing.

Answer (score 2):

**From grammatical point of view:**
From grammatical point of view, `AvailableBread` is a compound of an adjective and a noun that is grammatically correct, but not really proper for your case. In this point of view, `breadAvailable` is short form of `Bread is available` which is a sentence and informally is both correct and appropriate for your case.

**From branding point of view:**
It seems that your question is more related to branding and marketing subjects, not English grammar. If that's the case, I will go with `BreadAvailable.com`, because it is a sentence giving NEWS to users and better persuades them that bread is really available!

Answer (score 0):

AvailableBread.com has a slight connotation that it will provide a listing of all places where bread can be found, which is better if the site is aggregating listings of bread available elsewhere on the internet. BreadAvailable.com emphasizes that bread can be found here; it would work best if bread is hard to find and here is a guaranteed place to find it. I suppose it would in a (for me) slightly irritating sales pitch kind of way also work for an aggregator site.

So if the pitch / value proposition is that the site shows all places to find bread, I'd go with AvailableBread.com. If instead the emphasis is you can get (hard to find) bread here, then I'd go with BreadAvailable.com.